# H2 tag magically appearing

Tags: html, tags

I have this .html file with just these contents:

```
<html><body><div class="main_text">
<h2>H2 text<h2/>
<p class="normal">
Look ma no h2 tag darnit!
</p>
</div></body></html>
```

When I open that file in Safari, the `Look ma no h2 tag darnit!` part looks pretty big. I get suspicious. So view source, and I get

```
<html><body><div class="main_text">
<h2>H2 text<h2/>
<p class="normal">
Look ma no h2 tag darnit!
</p>
</div></body></html>
```

So it's just the same as the above.

Go to `Develop -> Show Web Inspector`, right click on `<html>`, select `Edit as HTML`, copy and paste and I get:

```
<html><head></head><body><div class="main_text">
<h2>H2 text</h2><h2>
<p class="normal">
Look ma no h2 tag darnit!
</p>
</h2></div></body></html>
```

Whoa! Where did that extra h2 tag come from??? What am I doing wrong here?

And just in case you were wondering, if I edit out the h2 stuff in the web inspector, the page displays as I intended it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<h2>H2 text<h2/>` should be `<h2>H2 text</h2>`. The browser is trying to recover from you having two start tags and no end tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your first closing tag is actually `<h2/>`, not `</h2>`. The browser is implicitly closing the first `<h2>`, and with its flexible interpretation of malformed html, starting a new one based on the improperly self-closed `<h2/>` thereafter. It's making a logical guess as to where this new second `<h2>` should be closed.